# How to make a USB Flash Drive readonly for all systems except mine, where only I have permissions to copy/write/delete stuff?

Tags: usb, permissions, usb-flash-drive, flash

So I need to share my USB Flash drive to a lot of people from time to time. My requirement is simple, others should not be able to copy or delete any data from my flash drive.
So far I've only tried diskpart set attribute readonly, which I have realised, only works on my computer and is as easily reversible.
Is there a way to achieve a complete control over my flash drive's content copy, write, delete options ?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: There are some devices with passcode/fingerprint protection that allow different access level for the drive.

Comment: If others can read the data, they can copy it, by definition.  I suggest you remove that part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

Your only option is to encrypt your data on the USB with a secret password.

You could use for example the free
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/).

You may create a VeraCrypt volume on the USB, which will look
externally like a simple file. For ultra-secret data, the VeraCrypt
volume can even disguise itself as unallocated space on the disk.
The required VeraCrypt software can also be stored on the USB disk
for accessing your data.

Comment: Sure, but how does encryption answers the question? The OP wants to have a drive with different permissions for different users, namely read-only for others. If access to data is a requirement then password must be provided and once decrypted it's read/write like if it wasn't encrypted. Veracrypt solves nothing, it just adds an additional hurdle that was asked/requested.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: With VeraCrypt his data is accessible only by himself. It's impossible to restrict access for a USB when used on other computers, especially if the other users are administrators on their own computer. If you have a better idea, you're welcome.

Comment: Exactly and no, I don't have a better idea because the answer to this question is NO, not use Veracrypt. You should've take the hint right from the first comment.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I don't fob off users with a No, as long as I have a useful idea. Different attitude.

Comment: **When the answer is no, the answer is no. If you want to be useful then you can expand and explain WHY the answer is no.** Presenting, in this case, encryption as an "useful idea" means you either don't understand the question or like to waste your and the OP's time by posting a non-answer. And no, it's NOT a matter of attitude unless that "attitude" is intellectual arrogance.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: That's an attitude that I don't accept - users come here with problems that are sometimes rather their own XY solutions. We're here to help with the underlying problem even when the request as-is is impossible. Call it intellectual arrogance if you feel like it.

Comment: Sure... Someone asks "can I drive from LA to Haiti?" (Hint: The answer is no, there's an ocean in-between). Not exactly an XY problem. Then your answer is "you can take a train from Rome to Naples". This is the level of absurdity you think is helpful. End of story.